# Cut a substring from the end until the first occurrence of a certain character

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-re

I have a string lets say something like below:
`abc$defg..hij/klmn`

How can I get substring which is cut out from last character until we encounter the `$` sign. Note `$` could be a special character and there could other special characters in the string.

The output should be:
`defg..hij/klmn`

I a using python 2.7 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `split` function:

```
your_string = "abc$defg..hij/klmn"
split_char = "$"

substring = your_string.split(split_char)[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

That is an alternate method. It checks each character from the end until a special character is met.

```
text = "abc$defg..hij/klmn"
newstring = text[::-1]

output = ""

for character in newstring:
    if character != "$":
        output += character
    else:
        break

print(output[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first get the occurrence of that first character and then slice from that `index` plus `1`:

```
testStr = "abc$defg..hij/klmn"
try:
    index = testStr.index()
    start = index + 1
    print(str[start:])
except:
    print("Not in string")
```

*Note*: This will return a single string from after the first `&` to the end. If you want multiple strings enclosed within `$`, the accepted answer works well.